The 'IdentityServicePackage' package did not load correctly
I have been fighting with Microsoft VS 2022 Community for 3 days now. I have spoken to several people to try to get help. Nothing I have tried works. How do I fix this?
--
The 'IdentityServicePackage' package did not load correctly. + The 'GlobalHubClientPackage' package did not load correctly.
The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more info by examining the file 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_34988e9b\ActivityLog.xml'
Restarting Visual Studio could help resolve this issue.
Continue to show this error message? [Y] [N]
I have tried:
Deleting cache files, Restarting VS, Re-installing VS, Downloading and installing an older version, Opening through a game, Using Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022 to download GACs
Opening through admin makes it work, but I seem to have to open it normally through the game I am trying to work with for it to open the correct folder and have the correct startup location.

How does the error occurs? What configuration change you have done and what extension you have installed? Could you provide relevant information displayed in ActivityLog.xml?

Any feedback? @Loree.dll

I forgot about this thread, I'm so sorry. It turned out that since nothing worked it had something to do with my windows install somehow? So I redownloaded windows and now it works just fine. @FeiXu
